Memcached-MemcacheIllegalInputError - Data values must be binary-safe: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-5: ordinal not in range(128
I'm doing some tests with memcached on my django project to understand if I can get benefit of it. But I stuck at unicode character caching. I read many article about it but still could not understand how can I make it work. Here is my code block:
def cache(request):
client = Client("127.0.0.1:11211")
cache_key = '123' # needs to be unique
cache_time = 86400 # time in seconds for cache to be valid

data = client.get(cache_key) # returns None if no key-value pair
if not data:
    print("setting cache")
    
    #data contains unicode characters - Throws an error
    datafromdb = Subject.objects.all()
    #unicode characters - Throws an error
    unicodestr="abçüıö"
    #encoded unicode characters - Working fine
    encodedunicodestr=str.encode("abçüıö")

    client.set(cache_key,unicodestr , cache_time)
else:
    print("getting from cache")
return HttpResponse(data)

So If I use str.encode on text values It works fine and data can be cached.
But If I retrieve data from database(postgres) and this data contains unicode memcached throws an error.
I'm wondering if is there a way to use str.unicode on my queryset/list etc that returned from database or something else may be.

Indent your code to have a [example].
